# How to measure Fracture in area using ArcGIS Cut and Fill?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, 3d-analyst, volume

I want to measure fracture in an area.I know I have to use cut and fill tool. But I wonder how to give input for this tool? it has Input before raster surface and Input after raster surface ! what shall I enter for these 2 options?like the image below.

[image]

Comment: If the offered Answer does not provide all the information that you need, you may want to edit your Question to provide more details about precisely what you are asking.  For example, the term "fracture" in the context you are using it may not be familiar to a large portion of potential answerers so may be best defines and/or illustrated.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cut Fill tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000tz000000.htm) is designed to show volume change, so you need to have a "before" raster (what the elevation surface was before fracture occurred) and an "after" raster (what the elevation surface is after fracture, or what it is now).

The elevation surface (also known as DEM) for the two different time periods can be made manually using a topo contour map, or digitally using LiDAR, but the method of finding/creating DEMs is probably outside the scope of this particular question.

Comment: Ok, but I don't know how to make these layers? like before raster and after raster! 
I don't know how to fill the fractures ?

Comment: They are both DEM layers (typically). If you're trying to actually fill fractures then that's a different operation -- measuring the [Sink](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000054000000) then using the [Fill](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000050000000) tool maybe? Cut Fill may not be the _best_ way to do this, if you don't already have a before/after; I can't think of an alternative off the top of my head, though.